# What skills complement the Toad of Hugeness?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I just unlocked this skill, but can't fathom how to use it in conjunction with my other skills. Since the giant toad sits there doing damage to one enemy, it seems rather useless when large crowds of monsters attack me (when I'm playing solo).

My first thought is to use something like Horrify or Mass Confusion to keep everything else away while using other attacks like Acid Rain, Haunt, Zombie Dogs, or Gargantuan. However, the benefit of using the Toad of Hugeness to incapacitate one enemy doesn't seem to make a huge difference if I'm using those other attacks anyway.

Is there another skill that I can currently use with Toad of Hugeness or are there other combinations of skills that I will eventually unlock that go better with Toad of Hugeness?

Comment: Good question, because I found the huge toad rather slow and underwhelming (at lvl ~20)

Comment: Toad of hugeness struck me as a very fun, and exceptionally ineffective skill. Its like a lame little brother to hex.

Comment: Lol.  The Newt of Tremendous Size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Toad of Hugeness for a while in a CC build. My build went like this:

Primary: Poison Dart (Splinters)
Secondary Plague of Toads (Toad of Hugeness)
1: Grasp of the Dead (Groping Eels)
2: Wall of Zombies (Unrelenting Grip)
3: Mass Confusion (Mass Hysteria)
4: Gargantuan (Restless Giant)
Passive: Jungle Fortitude, Spiritual Attunement, Pierce the Veil

I will happily admit that there is better CC that can be used on the Secondary, however I was finding against small-sized Champions, the Huge Toad would eat said Champion, thus removing it temporarily from battle. This proved to be particularly useful as the minions could then be dealt with before the Champion returns.

The size of the enemy is important as to whether the Toad will eat it or not. Big enemies (like Wood Wraiths) won't get eaten by the Toad.

Answer (score 0):

I've honestly not found Toad of Hugeness very useful at all. It is a single target CC effect with very little damage and since everything in this game fights in groups it is not a very effective use of an ability slot. Additionally, you can't even damage the target inside the toad until the throws it back up either.

It looks funny and is entertaining to use when you first get it, but the ability basically ends up just being weaker version of Hex. I've not used it a single time in Hell or Inferno.